# instagram-ruby-gem undefined method `query_values'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

Hi there i have been working on a project that graps the users instagram photos and let them to download it. To authenticate i use the gem called [instagram-ruby-gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem)
which is an offical ruby gem for instagram

```
def instagram_callback
  response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => "http://0.0.0.0:3000/oauth/callback")
  client = Instagram.client(:access_token => response.access_token)
  user = client.user
  raise client.user_recent_media.inspect
end

def instagram_login
  return redirect_to Instagram.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => "http://0.0.0.0:3000/oauth/callback")
end
```

When the instagram callback method is called there is an errors pops-up

undefined method `query_values' for #URI::HTTPS:0x0000010441f028 and it shows the line

```
 response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => "http://0.0.0.0:3000/oauth/callback")
```

I guess this is a gem bug maybe not but i am having the problem there is a issue about about it in the [git-hub page](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/issues/33) did any one have any solution for this ?

Comment: Dear all in the git-hub repo this error has been fixed you need to fix the faraday version of 0.7.6 there is a change in the behaviour of the faraday.
https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/issues/33

Answer (score 1):

I commented workaround on [github page](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/issues/33). 
Please try to use faraday version "0.7.6".